# Is it possible to restyle a picture after getting uploaded in paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

if pictures are uploaded using one style, how can i change the style of the uploaded picture after the picture is already uploaded. say if i want to change from tiny or thumb to original? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you specified for example two styles `:thumb` and `:grid` and uploaded image to it, then you already have **three** images by default: grid, thumb and original. So in your views you could just use `<your attachment>.path(:thumb)` or `<your attachment>.path(:grid)`.
2. Anyway if you added some more styles to your model you should call `rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles`.

[Documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)